# MenuItem causes the application to be slow

Tags: wpf, datagrid, menu, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a DataGrid which displays my data (the collection holds more than one type of data,
where for each type I wrote a DataTemplate). Basically, my DataGrid acts like a property Grid.

Normally, working with the datagrid is pretty fast. Every time I change the datagrid collection, its loads fast.

My problem is when I display some menuItem  (within contextmenu or Menu) it causes the application to be clumsy and act slow. My datagrid is been slowly.

I'm sure that the slowness is caused by the menu item.

Is this a known bug? What am I doing wrong? Anyone?

Here is the DataGrid Code

```
  <DataGrid Name="propsDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="#FFA9BFD4" RowBackground="#FFCADBE7"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
      <!--<DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name" IsReadOnly="true"   Width="100" MinWidth="22"  Binding="{Binding DisplayName,Converter={StaticResource propertyNameToDiplayNameConverter}}" />-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="true"   Width="100" MinWidth="22" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border  Background="#FFA9BFD4" 
                                     Visibility="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}"> 
                                <Expander Template="{StaticResource SimpleExpanderTemp}"  ExpandDirection="Left" 
                                     IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3,0,5,0"/>
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock   Text="{Binding DisplayName,Converter={StaticResource propertyNameToDiplayNameConverter}}"/>
                                        <!--Visibility="{Binding IsCategoryItem,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=VisForFalse}"/>-->
                        </Grid>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Property" IsReadOnly="true"   Width="1*" MinWidth="22" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Background="#FFA9BFD4"  Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource uiPropertyViewModelToObjConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is the menu item code:

```
  <Menu  Background="Transparent">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New"  Command="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:ApplicationCommands.NewProject}}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Load"  Command="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:ApplicationCommands.LoadProject}}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add scene" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:ApplicationCommands.AddScene}}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Export" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:ApplicationCommands.ExportProject}}"/>
            <!--<MenuItem Header="Import" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:ApplicationCommands.ImportProject}}"/>-->
            <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:ApplicationCommands.SaveProject}}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Save as" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:ApplicationCommands.SaveAsProject}}"/>
            <ns:RecentFileList x:Name="RecentFileList"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:ApplicationCommands.Exit}}"/>
        </MenuItem><!--File-->
```